# SyntaxError in MusicsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to Save Multiple Check box values to Database.When i run this code I got an error:- `premature end of char-class: /[\][\]\"]/`
and when I click on check box for selecting any check box value then it should display the details of that check box values below that page on only.
This is my code:

music.rb

```
class Music < ActiveRecord::Base

before_save do 
  self.genre.gsub!(/[\][\]\"]/,"") if attribute_present?("genre")


    end
end
```

musics_controller.rb

```
class MusicsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_music, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def index
    @musics = Music.all
   end

   def show
   end

  def new
   @music = Music.new
   end

  def edit
   end

  def create
   @music = Music.new(music_params)

   respond_to do |format|
    if @music.save
    format.html { redirect_to @music, notice: 'Music was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @music }
  else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @music.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
def update
   respond_to do |format|
    if @music.update(music_params)
     format.html { redirect_to @music, notice: 'Music was successfully updated.' }
     format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @music }
   else
     format.html { render :edit }
     format.json { render json: @music.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
   @music.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to musics_url, notice: 'Music was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
    def set_music
  @music = Music.find(params[:id])
end

def music_params
  params.require(:music).permit(:title, :artist, genre:[])
end
end
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. `/[\][\]\"]/` is not a valid regexp, and it's bad enough that I can't even guess what it's supposed to match. Please explain in words what kind of validation you want for `genre`, and provide some examples. Additionally, for best results, please ask one question at a time; if your question is "syntax error in `/[\][\]\"]/`, then all the rest is unnecessary, and likely to just distract potential answerers.

Comment: @Rohan do you want to store that checkbox ids in any other table or middle table ?

Comment: yes i want to store checkbox ids in middle table